# You must provide a request body if you set ContentLength>0 or SendChunked==true. Do this by calling [Begin]GetRequestStream before [Begin]GetResponse

Tags: asp.net, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I tried to upload file on oracle cloud infrastructure iaas but getting the error.I am not sure whether the file that  I attached in the body is in 
   correct format or not. ApI signing is correct and I am doubt only about 
   whether the code that I wrote is upto mark or not. The code snippet is mentioned below.
    The code Snippet :

```
            FileInfo f = new FileInfo(FileUpload1.FileName);
            byte[] filebyte =FileUpload1.FileBytes;

            var postdata = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(filebyte.ToString());
        Console.Write(postdata.Length);

            var tenancyId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BMCTenancyId"];
            var userId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BMCUserId"];
            var fingerprint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BMCFingerprint"];
            var privateKeyPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BMCPrivateKeyPath"];
            var privateKeyPassphrase = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BMCPrivateKeyPassphrase"];

            var signer = new RequestSigner(tenancyId, userId, fingerprint, privateKeyPath, privateKeyPassphrase);

            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            var uri = new Uri($"https://objectstorage.us-phoenix-1.oraclecloud.com/");

            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.Accept = "application/json";
            request.SendChunked = true;
            request.ContentType = "text/plain";

            request.ContentLength =postdata.Length;
        try
        {
            using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(postdata, 0, postdata.Length);
                stream.Close();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);

        }



            request.Headers["x-content-sha256"] = Convert.ToBase64String(SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(postdata));

            signer.SignRequest(request);

            Console.WriteLine($"Authorization header: {request.Headers["authorization"]}");

            ExecuteRequest(request);

            Console.WriteLine("The value of 'ContentLength' property after sending the data is {0}", request.ContentLength);
    }

        private static void ExecuteRequest(HttpWebRequest request)
        {
            try
            {
                var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                var response = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine($"Response: {response}");
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Exception occurred: {e.Message}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Response: {new StreamReader(e.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd()}");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, you'll need to update the URL to the following format:

```
var uri = new Uri($"https://objectstorage.us-phoenix-1.oraclecloud.com/n/{namespaceName}/b/{bucketName}/o/{objectName}");
```

Docs: https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/api/#/en/objectstorage/20160918/Object/PutObject

Also, can you please edit the question to include the complete error you are receiving, that will help with debugging.